# Filter Newline Delimited JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am trying to filter from a list of dictionaries returned via `json.dumps`. However, since it is newline-delimited JSON (where the dictionaries are not separated by commas), I am receiving an error.

```
>>>> print my_data
>>>> {u'mykey': 1234, u'color': u'red'} {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'orange'} {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'yellow'}
```

**CODE:**

```
key = 5678

test_data = json.dumps(my_data)
self.response.write(test_data)
  # test_data outputs {"mykey": 1234, "color": "red"} {"mykey": 5678, "color": "orange"} {"mykey": 5678, "color": "yellow"}

test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == key, test_data)
print test
```

**ERROR:**

> test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == key, test_data)
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

When I copy the same data into a Python interpreter, adding brackets and commas between each dictionary, it returns the correct output.

**CODE**

```
key = 5678

test_data = [
  {"mykey": 1234, "color": "red"},
  {"mykey": 5678, "color": "orange"},
  {"mykey": 5678, "color": "yellow"}]

test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == key, test_data)
print test
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [{'color': 'orange', 'mykey': 5678}, {'color': 'yellow', 'mykey': 5678}]

*How can I fix my code or the JSON output so that I can properly filter?*

**EDIT (Correction):**

I am looking for a solution using `self.response.write` not `print`.

While using @Ashish Ranjan's answer, I noticed that `print` has a different output than `self.response.write`. Recommended solutions should use `self.response.write`:

```
test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == key, test_data)
self.response.write(test)
```

Current outputs using @Ashish's solution are:

*Hard-coded data:*

```
my_data = "{u'mykey': 1234, u'color': u'red'} {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'orange'} {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'yellow'}"
test_data = ast.literal_eval("[" + re.sub(r'({[^\}]*})\s', r'\1,' , my_data) + "]")
test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == 5678, test_data)
self.response.write(test_data)
```

> [{u'mykey': 1234, u'color': u'red'}, {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'orange'}, {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'yellow'}][{u'mykey': 1234, u'color': u'red'}, {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'orange'}, {u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'yellow'}]

*From JSON object*:

```
dumped_data = json.dumps(my_data)
test_data = ast.literal_eval("[" + re.sub(r'({[^\}]*})\s', r'\1,' , dumped_data) + "]")
test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == 5678, test_data)
self.response.write(test_data)
```

> ({u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678},)({u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678},)

**Note:** Even testing with `print`, JSON data doesn't output results correctly. Instead, it prints each piece of data on a separate line:

> [{u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678}]
>
> [{u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678}]

All of these results are incorrect. I do not understand why `self.response.write` isn't working like `print`. (I've never come across this problem before so any insight would help.)

Comment: In the first example, `test_data` contains a `]` at the end and not at the beginning?

Comment: Edited (test_data doesn't have any brackets), thanks for pointing it out

Comment: can you post your what's your `my_data`?

Comment: @bruntime, added a "fix" algorithm. But could you add the output of `print my_data` to your question?

Comment: The output of `my_data` has been added for more clarification

Comment: @bruntime check the updated answer, working as expected.

Comment: @bruntime in your edited question, you've written `test = filter(...)` it should be `test_data = filter(...)`

Comment: also can you show what `dumped_data` looks like by printing it? is it same as `my_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `my_data` to a valid python list/dict before using `filter`.

You can use RegEx for this:

```
import re
import ast
test_data = ast.literal_eval("[" + re.sub(r'({[^\}]*})\s', r'\1,' , my_data) + "]")
```

RegEx [demo](https://regex101.com/r/weOLOw/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> test_data
[{u'mykey': 1234, u'color': u'red'},{u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'orange'},{u'mykey': 5678, u'color': u'yellow'}]
>>> test_data = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == 5678, test_data)
>>> test_data
[{u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678}, {u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678}]
```

**EDIT**

You need to use `json.dumps()` when using `self.response.write`. So, this will work :

```
self.response.write(json.dumps(test_data))
```

Comment: I've tested this code and it doesn't work as expected for me. Instead of printing `[{u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678}, {u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678}]`, Python is adding parentheses so the data looks like this instead `({u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678},)({u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678},)`.

Comment: it's a tuple, you can add `list` to convert it to a list i.e, `list(filter(...))`, it'll give you: `[{u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678}, {u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678}]`

Comment: you must be doing something wrong as I'm getting the correct output, python 2.x : https://repl.it/NIAJ/1, python 3.x : https://repl.it/NIAM/2

Comment: you are right. I just noticed that I'm using `self.response.write` instead of `print`. `print` works correctly but `self.response.write` returns `[{u'color': u'red', u'mykey': 1234}, {u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678}, {u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678}][{u'color': u'red', u'mykey': 1234}, {u'color': u'orange', u'mykey': 5678}, {u'color': u'yellow', u'mykey': 5678}]`. I will edit my question accordingly since I didn't realize there would be two different outputs.

Comment: @bruntime also you need to write : `json.dumps()` when using `self.response.write`. So, `self.response.write(json.dumps(test_data))` will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157403/discussion-between-bruntime-and-ashish-ranjan).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
s = r'{"mykey": 1234, "color": "red"} {"mykey": 5678, "color": "orange"} {"mykey": 5678, "color": "yellow"}'
```

You could *fix* the string into valid json objects like this:

```
delim = "}"
jsons =  [json.loads(token.strip() + delim) for token in s.split(delim) if token]
```

And then parse it:

```
key = 5678
test = filter(lambda thedata: thedata['mykey'] == key, jsons)
```

Here are working programs in [Python2](https://repl.it/NEmj/0) and [Python3](https://repl.it/NEnC/0).

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I get the error message: `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`.

Comment: @bruntime, could you explain what is line 1 in your program? Also added live programs of this code.

Comment: I was just testing this solution in PyCharm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks for including 2 working versions. I'll look into why it's not working for me.

Comment: I was unable to get this solution to work for me but I have marked your answer as helpful.